# Google map marker not showing the location after linking css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Store Locator of Google Map with current location in which I'm showing other location(other location's latitude and longitude is already in my database) in my radius of 200 miles and it is working fine but after linking css file in my page, everything is working fine except info window of markers of nearby locations is not showing.

Code here:-
   Index.html

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />-->
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"
                type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
        <!-- Cordova-1.5.0.js file will be here -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>            
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        var infoWindow;
        var locationSelect;
        var F_lat=null;
        var S_lat;

        function load() {
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
          //alert('hi1');
          onDeviceReady() ;
        }

       function onDeviceReady() {
          //alert('hi2');
          if(!!navigator.geolocation) {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                F_lat=position.coords.latitude;
                S_lat=position.coords.longitude;
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: map,
                    position: geolocate,
                    content:
                        '<h3>current Location</h3>' +
                        '<h3>Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '</h3>' +
                        '<h3>Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '</h3>'
                });

                map.setCenter(geolocate);

                 searchLocationsNear(F_lat,S_lat);
            });
           // searchLocationsNear(F_lat,S_lat);

        } else {
            document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = 'No Geolocation Support.';
        }
          infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

          locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
          locationSelect.onchange = function() {
            var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            if (markerNum != "none"){
              google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
            }
          };
          // if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          //   searchLocationsNear(F_lat,S_lat);
          //   alert('prakash:-'+F_lat);
          //  } else {
          //    alert(address + ' not found');
          //  }

       }

       function searchLocations() {
         //var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
         var address = prompt("Please enter your location", ""); 
         if(address){

         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
           // alert('prakash:-'+results[0].geometry.location.lng());
           } else {
             alert(address + ' not found');
           }
         });
       }else{
        alert('Please enter address');
       }
       }

       function clearLocations() {
         infoWindow.close();
         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
           markers[i].setMap(null);
         }
         markers.length = 0;

         locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
         var option = document.createElement("option");
         option.value = "none";
         option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
         locationSelect.appendChild(option);
       }

       function searchLocationsNear(lat1,lng2) {
         clearLocations();
         if(F_lat){

         var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + lat1 + '&lng=' + lng2 + '&radius=200';
       }
       else if(F_lat===null){
        // var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
         var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + lat1 + '&lng=' + lng2 + '&radius=200';
       }
          //var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
         downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
           var xml = parseXml(data);
           var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
           var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
             var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
             var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
             var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

             createOption(name, distance, i);
             createMarker(latlng, name, address);
             bounds.extend(latlng);
           }
           map.fitBounds(bounds);
           locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
           locationSelect.onchange = function() {
             var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
             google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
           };
          });
        }

        function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
          //alert(latlng+''+name+''+address);
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }

        function createOption(name, distance, num) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = num;
          option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
          locationSelect.appendChild(option);
        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
              new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
              new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request.responseText, request.status);
            }
          };

          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);
        }

        function parseXml(str) {
          if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            doc.loadXML(str);
            return doc;
          } else if (window.DOMParser) {
            return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
          }
        }

        function doNothing() {}

        //]]>
      </script>
      </head>

      <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="load()">
       <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <!-- header start -->
        <div data-role="header">
          <div class="top-home-left">Vision Zero</div>
          <div class="top-home-right">
            <a href="tel:311" onclick="return call();"><img src="images/call.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- header end -->
        <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select></div>
        <!-- <div class="map">f</div> -->
          <div data-role="content" style="padding:0;">
        <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <!-- bottom start -->
      <div class="bottom">
              <div class="bottom-btn1"><a href="setting.html"><img src="images/settings39.png"  alt=""></a></div>
                <div class="bottom-btn2"><a href="#" onclick="searchLocations()"><img src="images/magnifier5.png" alt=""></a></div>
                <div class="bottom-btn3"><a href="area.html"><img src="images/folder5.png" alt="" ></a></div>
                <div class="bottom-btn4"><a href="GoogleMapDirections.html"><img src="images/map2.png"  alt=""></a></div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        <!-- bottom end -->

      </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

And CSS file:- style.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Body Panel Start */
body {

    color:#fff; 
    line-height:24px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:20px;
}
a, a > * {
    color: #4ac3f0;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease, border .3s ease, color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease, border .3s ease, color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color .3s ease, border .3s ease, color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s ease, border .3s ease, color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color .3s ease, border .3s ease, color .3s ease, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
 *::-moz-selection {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00AB00;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: none;
}
*::selection {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00AB00;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    line-height:100%;
}
p {

    font-size:14px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;

}

.contenair { width:100%; }

.contenair ul { width:100%; }
.contenair li { list-style:none; color:#fff; }
.contenair a { text-decoration:none; color:#fff; line-height:35px; background:#262626; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px; padding:6px; display:block; margin-bottom:10px;  }
.contenair a:hover { background:#222222; }

.top { width:100%; position:fixed; top:0; }
.top-left { width:10%; float:left; background:#00837b url(../images/top-line.jpg) repeat-y right top; }
.top-middle { width:80%; float:left; }
.top-tight { width:10%; float:left; background:#00837b url(../images/top-line.jpg) repeat-y left top; }

.top-home-left {width:90%; text-align:center; background:#008d84; color:#fff; padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; float:left; }
.top-home-right {width:10%; text-align:center; background:#00837b url(../images/top-line.jpg) repeat-y left top; color:#fff; float:left; }
.top-home-right a { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; }
.top-home-right a:hover { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; background:#00a99e; }
.bottom {width:100%; background:#222222; color:#fff;  position:fixed; bottom:0; }

.bottom-btn1 { width:25%; float:left; background:#262626 url(../images/bottom-line.jpg) repeat-y right top; text-align:center;   }
.bottom-btn1 a { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; }
.bottom-btn1 a:hover {  display:block; background:#00a99e; }

.bottom-btn2 { width:25%; float:left;  background:#222222 url(../images/bottom-line.jpg) repeat-y right top; text-align:center; }
.bottom-btn2 a { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; }
.bottom-btn2 a:hover {  display:block; background:#00a99e; }

.bottom-btn3 { width:25%; float:left;  background:#262626 url(../images/bottom-line.jpg) repeat-y right top; text-align:center; }
.bottom-btn3 a { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; }
.bottom-btn3 a:hover {  display:block; background:#00a99e; }

.bottom-btn4 { width:25%; float:left;  background:#222222 url(../images/bottom-line.jpg) repeat-y right top; text-align:center; }
.bottom-btn4 a { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; }
.bottom-btn4 a:hover {  display:block; background:#00a99e; }


.map { width:100%; height:700px; background:url(../images/map2.jpg) no-repeat left top; }
.map img { width:100%; }


/* setting */


.inner-top-right {width:90%; text-align:center; background:#008d84; color:#fff; padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; float:left; }
.inner-top-left {width:10%; text-align:center; background:#00837b url(../images/top-line.jpg) repeat-y right top; color:#fff; float:left; }
.inner-top-left a { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; }
.inner-top-left a:hover { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; background:#00a99e; }

.setting-bg { width:100%; background:#00a99e url(../images/map.png) no-repeat center top; height:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:-1;}
.setting-wrapper { width:70%; margin:0 auto; padding-top:100px; }
.setting-left { width:70%; float:left; margin-bottom:30px;   }
.setting-right { width:30%; float:right; margin-bottom:30px;    }



/* area */

.area-top-middle {width:80%; text-align:center; background:#008d84; color:#fff; padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; float:left; }

.area-top-left {width:10%; text-align:center; background:#00837b url(../images/top-line.jpg) repeat-y right top; color:#fff; float:left; }
.area-top-left a { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; }
.area-top-left a:hover { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; background:#00a99e; }

.area-top-right {width:10%; text-align:center; background:#00837b url(../images/top-line.jpg) repeat-y left top; color:#fff; float:left; }
.area-top-right a { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; }
.area-top-right a:hover { padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; display:block; background:#00a99e; }

.text-center { text-align:center; }

.area-textbox { width:100%; border:0px; background:#fff; outline:none; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px 0px 10px 0px; text-align:center; font-size:14px; }
.area-btn { width:60%; border:0px; background:#222222; outline:none; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom:10px; padding:12px 0px 12px 0px; color:#fff; cursor:pointer; text-align:center; font-size:14px;  }

/* Routes */
```

Comment: DEBUG: Try to disable each class one at a time and see which specific class is causing the problem. You can even see the applied class to an element in the developer tools of browser.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao, I did it many times but not working out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
icon: getMarkerImage(color),
```

With

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
          //alert(latlng+''+name+''+address);
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            icon: getMarkerImage(color) //New Added
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
```

Set image using

```
function getMarkerImage(iconStr) {
    if ((typeof (iconStr) == "undefined") || (iconStr == null)) {
        iconStr = "red";
    }
    if (!icons[iconStr]) {
        icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(""http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker""+ iconStr +"".png"",
        //icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images1/small-marker-truck.png",
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
        new google.maps.Size(26, 32),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
        new google.maps.Point(9, 32));
    }
    return icons[iconStr];
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 64.27.9.81/~prakash/Traffic_App/:160     and 
Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined

Comment: @cracker the MarkerImage class is deprecated, you should use the [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) class instead

Comment: i think icon is used for the shape and setting up the size itn't it?